# HDFS live node showing as decommissioned

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

I have 5 datanodes in my Cloudera cluster (CDH4) and all are showing as healthy.

The only service with an issue is HDFS which is showing under replication. When I go to host:50070/dfsnodelist.jsp?whatNodes=LIVE I'm seeing all 5 nodes, of which only one of them is shwoing is in Service. The rest of them are decommissioned.

I'm seeing a lot of information about removing the decommissioned nodes but very little on how to recommission. As far as cloudera manager is concerned, these nodes are active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that is strange. Althought Cloudera manager thinks they're okay, I thought I'd try decommissioning the datanodes and then recommissioning them as a last ditch. It seems to have fixed the reporting as decommissioned

In addition its fixed my underreplication issue as well.